# Elantech Mouse Touchpad not working well

Tags: debian, ubuntu, touchpad

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu/Debian (GNOME) machine:

My mouse touchpad does not work correctly (right-click not recognized, cannot do 2 finger drag and drop/highlight) on Debian, but it **does work properly in Ubuntu**.

I have so far overwritten `.conf` files in Debian with `.conf` files from Ubuntu in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and restarted X, and rebooted. However I still have this problem.

I am unsure as to where to go without having a program configure everything for me. If possible I would like to know how to fix this, and where I am getting my configurations from.

**Outputs:**

---

**ORIGINALLY** I did not have a `/etc/dev/X11/xorg.conf` file, or a `/etc/dev/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory (neither Ubuntu or Debian). I then made this file by doing `X -configure` and copying the `xorg.config.new` file to etc/dev/X11/xorg.conf`

Output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log |grep Elantech`:

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7981284/)

## More steps taken:

From Ubuntu:

- Opened tty,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- `sudo service lightdm stop` stop lightdm
- `sudo X -configure` grab X configuration
- `sudo start lightdm` re-start lightdm

Next steps are to move to Debian, and see if mouse works.

- It does not.

  ---

Compared `X -configure` from Debian, and Ubuntu:

### (Debian)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "record"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # 
        #Option     "DRI"                   # []
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # 
        #Option     "Tiling"                # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # []
        #Option     "Shadow"                # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # []
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # []
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"        # []
        #Option     "Throttle"              # []
        #Option     "UseVmap"               # []
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # 
        #Option     "DelayedFlush"          # []
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # []
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # []
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # []
        #Option     "Rotate"                # 
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # 
        #Option     "debug"                 # []
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

### (Ubuntu)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### : "%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # []
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # 
        #Option     "Backlight"             # 
        #Option     "DRI"                   # 
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # 
        #Option     "Tiling"                # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # []
        #Option     "VSync"                 # []
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # []
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # []
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # []
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # []
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # 
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # 
        #Option     "TearFree"              # []
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # []
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # []
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # []
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

I do not notice a difference between the pointing devices.

Output of `synclient -l`:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 130
RightEdge               = 3130
TopEdge                 = 96
BottomEdge              = 1697
FingerLow               = 1
FingerHigh              = 1
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 163
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 74
HorizScrollDelta        = 74
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0537634
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 297
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 1
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 1
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 18
VertHysteresis          = 18
ClickPad                = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this! I am sure there is a different way of doing this. What I did was:

- On Ubuntu (working system):

  - `synclient -l > ubuntusettings`
- Loaded Debian (problem system):

  - Copied the **ubuntusettings** file from Ubuntu system to Debian.
  - Copied this script [synclient-load](http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/synclient-load) to a blank text (with .py extension) 
    *This is written for earlier version of python, so you will need python 2.x*
  - Used `chmod +x synclient-load` to make script executable.
  - Ran the command `python synclient-load.py ubuntusettings`

My mouse can now drag & drop, right-click, and drag & highlight with 2 fingers. I am sure I could have gone through every syclient setting and manually reconfigured, or even configured the file that synclient is reading from (according to man page, it reads from  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/etc/X11/XF86Config-4` however neither one of these were easily editable for me as they did not exist, and replacing/creating the xorg.conf file did not do anything).

This script instead takes everything from a dumped synclient file, puts everything into a dictionary parses the info, and sets the settings from that dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/ElantechTouchpad), settings in GNOME can override the system-wide settings.  Have you tried to configure the desired behavior in the `Mouse and Pointing Device Settings` in the `GNOME Control Center`?

Also check to make sure that you have a configuration file in `xorg.conf.d` to configure your touchpad.  I believe this can be included in your `xorg.conf` file but it makes sense to break it out to make it more understandable and easier to play with.  I am on arch linux, but I went through this process of configuring my touchpad when I installed it.  Below is my `synaptics.conf` file.  [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Configuration) page on the ArchWiki can help you find the configuration options to put in synaptics.conf, and has some additional information on the settings GNOME overwrites and how to reset them with `dconf`.

My `synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        #Option  "Device"        "/dev/input/mouse0"
#        Option  "Protocol"      "auto-dev"         
#        Option  "LeftEdge"      "1700"             
#        Option  "RightEdge"     "5300"             
#        Option  "TopEdge"       "1700"             
#        Option  "BottomEdge"    "4200"             
#        Option  "FingerLow"     "25"               
#        Option  "FingerHigh"    "30"               
#        Option  "MaxTapTime"    "180"              
#        Option  "MaxTapMove"    "220"              
        Option  "VertScrollDelta" "-100"            
        Option  "HorizScrollDelta" "-100"            
        Option  "PalmDetect"        "5"
#        Option  "MinSpeed"      "0.20"             
#        Option  "PalmDetect"      "5"             
#        Option  "AccelFactor" "0.00900"             
#        Option  "SHMConfig"     "1"               
        Option  "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"        
        Option  "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "1"        
        Option  "NaturalScroll"         "1"
        Option  "VertEdgeScroll"        "1"
#        Option  "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
#        Option  "HorizEdgeScroll"       "1"
        Option  "TapButton1"            "1"
        Option  "TapButton2"            "2"
        Option  "TapButton3"            "3"
EndSection
```

Comment: Yes I have tried to change this through Mouse and Pointing Device Settings. It does not give options through the GUI to change things like the drag and drop with 2 finger control, or change the right-click to a positional click on the pad.

Comment: What is the output of `synclient -l`?

Comment: for Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: `synclient -l` on either should show you the current configuration options set for your touchpad.  You can compare this to your settings in your `synaptics.conf`.

Comment: I have updated answer with `synclient -l` output. Sorry that took forever to respond. I am unable to find my synaptics.conf